# Retrieve the IP address of a router I was connected to before

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am looking for a simple answer to the above question. I have logged on to a router that I know the network name of, and which is in my key chain, but I cannot find its IP address. Is there a way to retrieve it?

I have also sent email through that router before (if that helps).

Comment: Yes, look at the default gateway IP address which you are assigned by that router or a DHCP server. Just check the TCP/IP properties. How try `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`.

Comment: *Please answer with a simple no or yes, and here is how.* It's not really necessary to ask for an answer since this site isn't a discussion forum and doesn't allow anything but answers to be posted in the answer box.

Comment: What operating system are you on? Are you trying to retrieve the internal or external address (if applicable)?

Comment: I want to connect to it from outside, so I guess this will be the external address.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases the address of the WiFi router is `192.168.1.1` (or sometimes `192.168.0.1`).

Use your operating system dependent utility (as `ipconfig` in Windows shell or `ifconfig` in Linux shell) and search output for *Default Gateway* (gateway == router).

Here is the appropriate row from `ipconfig` utility:

```
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

**Addendum:**

If you wanted the *external* address, use any of feedback pages as [hashemian's Who am I?](https://www.hashemian.com/whoami/)

Comment: No, you refer to the internal address. I am looking for the external one.

Comment: I put addendum to my answer how to accomplish it.